I'm developing a WinUi3 app and im using "using LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware;" , "...Unavailable"
error
I'm getting this error instead of getting the RAM Gbs and the motherboard name, but the same function to get the graphics card name is working so I really don't know what the issue is.
Function to get the RAM Gb:
private string GetRAMName()
{
     foreach (var hardware in _computer.Hardware)
     {
         if (hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.Memory)
         {
             hardware.Update();

             foreach (var sensor in hardware.Sensors)
             {
                 if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Data && sensor.Name.Contains("Available Memory"))
                 {
                     // Check if we can calculate the total memory from available memory
                     double? totalMemory = sensor.Value; // Available memory in GB
                     if (totalMemory.HasValue)
                     {
                         // Assuming available memory + used memory gives the total
                         return $"Total RAM: {totalMemory.Value:F2} GB";
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     return "Total RAM size unavailable";
}

Function to get the motherboard Name
private string GetMotherboardName()
{
    foreach (var hardware in _computer.Hardware)
    {
        if (hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.Cooler)
        {
            return hardware.Name ?? "Motherboard name unavailable";
        }
    }
    return "Motherboard name unavailable";
}


the error image  is in the "error" href

What you are showing isn't any error message - it is just the default return value of your GetRAMName() method. I recommend What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? and as a personal opinion naming a method suggesting returning a manufacturer name but instead returning the RAM size not optimal.
